# how to access context in serializer queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking for a way to access the context to filter by current user

```
 class RemovePermissionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        user_permissions = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            many=True, queryset=Permission.objects.filter(user = context.get('request').user)
        )
```

I can't access context becuase it's undefined, neither self.context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve that override **get_fields** method in **RemovePermissionsSerializer** as shown below:

```
class RemovePermissionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

def get_fields(self):
    fields = super().get_fields()
    # If you want your logic according to request method
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request and request.method.lower() == "<your method here>":
        fields['user_permissions'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            many=True, queryset=Permission.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        )
    
    return fields
```

If you want to change representation according to the action you can do something like this:

```
class RemovePermissionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

def get_fields(self):
    fields = super().get_fields()
    # IF you want your logic according to action
    view = self.context.get('view')
    if view and view.action == "<action name>":
        fields['user_permissions'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            many=True, queryset=Permission.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        )
    return fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide the context when initialising the serializer? If you want the context to be available within the Serializer you will have to provide it yourself, like:

```
serializer = RemovePermissionsSerializer(instance, context={"request": request})
```

or

```
serializer = RemovePermissionsSerializer(instance, context={"user": request.user})
```

That is, the request context is not automatically available in the serializer

Comment: yessir I did, serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

Comment: Can you update your post so we can see the error that you are getting? It would also be good to see the full viewset from which you are initiating the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to fabricate the serializer with a method, something like:

```
def get_remove_permission_serializer(user):      
    class RemovePermissionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
                user_permissions = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
                    many=True, queryset=Permission.objects.filter(user = user)
                )
    return RemovePermissionsSerializer
```

I think it is way cleaner than the accepted answer, but it might be an anti-pattern